# After changing the command prefix, the old one can still be used

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command to change the prefix of my bot. The command works, but after changing the prefix, the previous prefix can still be used. But I want that after a change only the new prefix can be used.

This is my code so far:

```js
const db = require("quick.db")
const { default_prefix } = require("../../configs/config.json")
const config = require('../../configs/config.json')

module.exports = {
config: {
  name: "newprefix",
  category: "moderation",
  usage: "prefix <new-prefix>",
  description: "Change the guild prefix",
  aliases: ["npx", "spx"],
},
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    //PERMISSION
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "You do not have permission [ADMINISTRATOR] to perform this act",
          color: config.embedcolor
        }
      })
    }
    
    if(!args[0]) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "You need to enter the prefix to want to set",
          color: config.embedcolor
        }
      })
    } 
    
    if(args[1]) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "You can not set prefix a double argument",
          color: config.embedcolor
        }
      })
    }
    
    if(args[0].length > 3) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "You can not send prefix more than 3 characters",
          color: config.embedcolor
        }
      })
    }
    
    if(args.join("") === default_prefix) {
      db.delete(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
     return await message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        title: "Prefix resetted ☑",
        color: config.embedcolor
      }
    })
    }
    
    db.set(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`, args[0])
  await message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      title: `Seted Bot Prefix to ${args[0]}`,
      color: config.embedcolor
    }
  })
    
  }
}
```

And this is my config:

```json
    {       
        "prefix": ".",
        "embedcolor": "#1DCAD3", 
        "dev": "582495058352406528",   
        "token": "My token is here",
        "hostedBy": "true"            
    }
```

How can I make sure that only the new prefix can be used after the change?

Comment: what does that even mean

Comment: @JoeMoore what do you not understand tell me so i can explain here

Comment: the grammar of your question didnt make sense, it has now been edited

Comment: @JoeMoore sorry my bad now if you can understand is it possible for you to help me?

Comment: yes, I'll take a look now

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with `quickDB`, but I think some of your logic is wrong.

Assuming the syntax you use is correct, and the database updates, make sure that in your command handler you are using the new prefix, instead of a default one. You should make it so that the prefix is loaded during the handling of every message you send i.e. in your `bot.on("message")` event.

I would recommend against deleting entire tables or rows in your database, and simply alter them, this could be your problem, but I am not familiar with your code, or `quickDB`.